# XML SOAP POST error, what am I doing wrong?

Tags: python, xml, soap, post

So I am trying to do an API call via a XML SOAP POST the error I am getting is: "Object reference not set to an instance of an object"

```
site = 'https://webservices.autotask.net/atservices/1.5/atws.asmx'
data = """<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <soap:Body>
    <queryxml>
      <entity>contact</entity>
        <query>
          <field>firstname<expression op="equals">George</expression>
          </field>
        </query>
    </queryxml>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>"""

headers = {
    'Content-Type': 'application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8',
    'Host': 'webservices.autotask.net',
    'Content-Type': 'text/xml; charset=utf-8',
    'Content-Length': len(data),
    'SOAPAction': "http://autotask.net/ATWS/v1_5/query"
    } 
site = 'https://webservices.autotask.net/atservices/1.5/atws.asmx'
auth_handler = urllib2.HTTPBasicAuthHandler()
auth_handler.add_password(realm='webservices.autotask.net',
                          uri=site,
                          user='user,
                          passwd='pw')
opener = urllib2.build_opener(auth_handler)
urllib2.install_opener(opener)
page = urllib2.urlopen(site)
print(data)
req = urllib2.Request(site, data, headers)
response = urllib2.urlopen(req)
the_page = response.read()
print(the_page)
```

The auth works and I have done succesfull calls with this code, the only thing that is diffrent now is the data XML SOAP POST. I will try suds.

No Traceback only web server error:

Print out of the XML SOAP POST that I am sending:

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
      <soap:Body>
        <queryxml>
          <entity>contact</entity>
            <query>
              <field>firstname<expression op="equals">George</expression>
              </field>
            </query>
        </queryxml>
      </soap:Body>
    </soap:Envelope>`

The response:

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"><soap:Body><queryResponse xmlns="http://autotask.net/ATWS/v1_5/"><queryResult><ReturnCode>-1</ReturnCode><EntityResults /><EntityResultType /><Errors><ATWSError><Message>Object reference not set to an instance of an object.</Message></ATWSError><ATWSError><Message>Error reading in Query XML.</Message></ATWSError></Errors><EntityReturnInfoResults /></queryResult></queryResponse></soap:Body></soap:Envelope>`

Any ideas?

George

Comment: No, no ideas at all. I might have some, though, if you posted the code you're using, and the traceback you get.

Comment: are you sure you're using python and not .NET?

Comment: Are you building the SOAP POST body manually? Using [python-suds](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/suds) could make calling your SOAP service much easier.

Comment: @Brian Yes python, but the server takes SOAP 1.1 and 1.2

Comment: @Daniel No Traceback only web server error.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Autotask has an ancient API on IIS 6... to deal with the microsoft crapstack you have to escape the XML you push over there as CDATA.  Here's what worked for me as the soap body, within the

```
<ins0:query>
```

tags:

```
<ins0:sXML>
<![CDATA[<queryxml>
<entity>contact</entity>
<query>
<field>phone<expression op='equals'>#{phone}</expression></field>
</query>
</queryxml>]]>
</ins0:sXML>
```

Comment: I gave up on python/AT and found a library on their forums in .net and it worked for what I needed. I will try this again if I come back to AT api, thanks.

Comment: Sorry you had to .net it.  Perhaps in another 10 years they will have a nice REST API... and electric lights...

Comment: @Eskim0 We'll have to wait 2 more years :/ no rest API yet

Answer (score 2):

George, here is an example of calling one of the test web services on `webservicex.net`:

```
import suds
url = 'http://www.webservicex.net/stockquote.asmx?WSDL'
client = suds.client.Client(url=url)
print client.service.GetQuote('IBM')

<StockQuotes>
  <Stock>
     <Symbol>IBM</Symbol>
     <Last>159.93</Last><Date>3/7/2011</Date><Time>4:00pm</Time>
     <Change>-1.90</Change><Open>161.60</Open><High>162.98</High>
     <Low>158.85</Low><Volume>5318064</Volume>
     <MktCap>195.0B</MktCap><PreviousClose>161.83</PreviousClose>
     <PercentageChange>-1.17%</PercentageChange>
     <AnnRange>116.00 - 166.25</AnnRange>
     <Earns>11.52</Earns><P-E>14.05</P-E>
     <Name>International Bus</Name>
  </Stock>
</StockQuotes>
```

You should be able to do HTTP basic authentication by passing in username and
password on the constructor:

```
client = suds.client.Client(url=url, username='user', password='pw')
```

Good luck with suds!

Comment: No go, I know that the headers are not the problem. It is the darn XML. I have done other calls to this API with identical headers. Ugh I am stuck, I asked on their site to confirm my XML, will see what happens.

Comment: They can't figure it out either, so I rewrote it into VB.net, but now getting a NRE, even though I copied it directly from the API PDF.

Answer (score 0):

The reply above indicating that their API is "dated" is a little bit of an understatement. That being said, the problem you are experiencing is because your XML is not formatted properly.

There is nothing crazy that they are expecting nor need from you other than a properly formatted XML body.

Eskim0 hand crafts a body for you, but the problem is that you probably don't see what he has actually done. He is crafting an "sXML" body within the larger SOAP request.

Most libraries (perl, python and php definitely all can do this) supply a method whereby you can pass in some queryxml and "sXML"ify it. This is the kind of thing you really shouldn't be trying to do by hand, as there are just too many details to keep track of.

So for example, in perl you'd do this:

```
$soap->query(SOAP::Data->value($query)->name('sXML'))
```

which would issue an sXML version of string $query to the query method at the soap endpoint.